# How do I add sql query data to a table in itextsharp pdf creator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, itext

I have multiple tables in my database that I need to retrieve data from then add each table to a single cell in the pdf table. My code is as follows below. I have created the select statements. Now, I need to get each statement and put them in its respective cell, so about_me goes in col 2 row 1, education goes in col 2 row 2 etc.

Any ideas?

```
protected void pdfcreatorbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //setup connection to SQL and retrieve data
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RIADDConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand aboutmecmd    = new SqlCommand ("SELECT about_me FROM about_me",conn);
                SqlCommand educationcmd  = new SqlCommand ("SELECT education_name, details FROM education",conn); 
                SqlCommand employmentcmd = new SqlCommand ("SELECT job_name,details_emp,Year_started,year_finished FROM employment",conn);
                SqlCommand hobbiescmd    = new SqlCommand ("SELECT hobby_type,details_h FROM hobbies",conn);
                SqlCommand skillscmd     = new SqlCommand ("SELECT skill,rating FROM skills",conn);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();




            Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 42, 35);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("MatthewCremonaCV.PDF", FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open(); //open document file

            PdfPTable maintable = new PdfPTable(2); //declare new table
                maintable.AddCell("image"); //col 1 row 1
                maintable.AddCell(""); //col 2 row 1
                maintable.AddCell("About Me"); //col 1 row 2
                maintable.AddCell(""); //col 2 row 2
                maintable.AddCell("Education"); //col 1 row 3
                maintable.AddCell(""); //col 2 row 3
                maintable.AddCell("Skills"); //col 1 row 4
                maintable.AddCell(""); //col 2 row 4
                maintable.AddCell("Employment History"); //col 1 row 5
                maintable.AddCell(""); //col 2 row 5
                maintable.AddCell("Hobies"); //col 1 row 6
                maintable.AddCell(""); //col 2 row 6
                maintable.AddCell("Contact"); //col 1 row 7
               // maintable.AddCell("Mobile: 123456"\n"email:matthewriadd@gmail.com"); //col 2 row 7
            doc.Add(maintable);

            PdfPTable table = new datatable()

            doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result set either as a DataTable/DataSet.

```
var ds = new DataSet();
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(<command>);
da.Fill(ds);
```

Once you hydrate that DataSet, you can pull the data via the Tables and Rows properties:

```
var aboutMe = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["about_me"];
```

Keep in mind that the object being returned is an object, so be sure to cast to the appropriate type.

```
mainTable.AddCell(aboutMe.ToString());
```